# How to execute consecutive commands in Cmder using batch file, e.g. enter the shell of a Docker container and then execute another one?

Tags: docker, batch-file, conemu, cmder

I am using a batch file for the Cmder startup and here is what I have there:

```
ConEmu.exe /single /cmd cmd /k "%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat & timeout 10 & docker exec -it processador-1 bash" -new_console:n:t:cad
```

The problem is, after entering the Docker container shell, I want to run another command `lein trampoline run` but none of the solutions found on the Internet is working (using &, && or ||).

Does anybody know if there is a way to achieve this?

P.S. Another thing I was trying to do is to set alias for `lein trampoline run`, as far as I understand I have to do it inside Docker itself and not in Cmder, but is there a way other than putting it in an image build?

Appreciate your answers!